# syslog: on ubuntu, how to configure rotation and gzip'ing of syslog files?

Tags: unix, logging, ubuntu, syslog

how do you configure rotation of syslog log files on ubuntu?

in my /etc/syslog.conf, i have this line:

local1.*  /var/log/log.txt

over time, the following backup files have appeared:

/var/log/log.txt.0.gz
/var/log/log.txt.1.gz

how do i configure how often these files get generated, and how to clean them out?

Comment: Just a note: you might get a better response at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running (this should tell us what version of syslogd and logrotate), and what do you want the behavior to be?

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu uses two log rotation mechanisms.

System log files which are configured via **/etc/syslog.conf** are rotated through **/etc/cron.*/sysklogd** which in turn uses **/usr/sbin/syslogd-listfiles** to get the list of files which need to be rotated.

The other tool is **logrotate** which is configured through **/etc/logrotate.conf** and scripts in **/etc/logrotate.d**

The advantage of the sysklogd mechanism is that new syslog files added to syslog.conf are automatically rotated without writing an extra logrotate script.
**syslogd-listfiles** is a bit complex and it rotates some logfiles on a daily bases which is not always useful on an inactive system.
So I set `$everything=0 ;` to disable the daily rotation of *.* syslog entries thus making the default to rotate purely based on log file size.